# Fit function cannot perform reduce with flexible type

Tags: python, linear-regression, databricks

I have a dataset with areas and prices from 42 apartments. I'm using python with databricks and I loaded a csv file with `,` as column delimiter. Later, I specified area as integer and price as double. Then I import libraries for graphs and do regression:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model
```

Later I read my database:

```
aptos=sqlContext.read.format('csv').options(header='true',
interSchema='true').load('/FileStore/tables/yl3r1mgv1507304115516/aptos_dataset-5ad32.csv')
display(aptos)
```

With the following lines, I created input variables with columns from the database:

```
X=aptos.select("area").collect()
Y=aptos.select("precio").collect()
```

Then I create my regression model:

```
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
```

At this point I have no problem. But when I run the following line:

```
regr.fit(X,Y)
```

I obtain the error:

```
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

I can see more details:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2158797891361999> in <module>()
      1 
      2 
----> 3 regr.fit(X,Y)

/databricks/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.pyc in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    517         X, y, X_offset, y_offset, X_scale = self._preprocess_data(
    518             X, y, fit_intercept=self.fit_intercept, normalize=self.normalize,
--> 519             copy=self.copy_X, sample_weight=sample_weight)
    520 
    521         if sample_weight is not None:

/databricks/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.pyc in _preprocess_data(X, y, fit_intercept, normalize, copy, sample_weight, return_mean)
    197             else:
    198                 X_scale = np.ones(X.shape[1])
--> 199         y_offset = np.average(y, axis=0, weights=sample_weight)
    200         y = y - y_offset
    201     else:

/databricks/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.pyc in average(a, axis, weights, returned)
    933 
    934     if weights is None:
--> 935         avg = a.mean(axis)
    936         scl = avg.dtype.type(a.size/avg.size)
    937     else:

/databricks/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.pyc in _mean(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
     63         dtype = mu.dtype('f8')
     64 
---> 65     ret = umr_sum(arr, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
     66     if isinstance(ret, mu.ndarray):
     67         ret = um.true_divide(

TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

I apologize but I can't share my database. I'm new with Python, I have more expertise with R. I will grateful with your help.

Comment: What's the imported data's schema? You probably have strings for `X` and `Y`. Also, it's `inferSchema='true'` not `interSchema='true'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Abdou. There was a typing error reading my database, this is the right way:

```
    aptos=sqlContext.read.format('csv').options(header='true', inferSchema='true').load('/FileStore/tables/yl3r1mgv1507304115516/aptos_dataset-5ad32.csv')
```

Now regression is working:

```
regr.fit(X,Y)
Out[4]: LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=1, normalize=False)
```